# How to instantiate a `DateTime` object at compile time?

Tags: compile-time, nim-lang

Nim 2 will have the ability to instantiate objects with default values for its fields (Here the merged PR on the devel branch: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/pull/20480). The feature is already available on nim's devel branch.
Given that, I would like to be able to have this default instantiation for fields with `DateTime` types.

Something like this:

```
import std/times

type A = object
  d: DateTime = times.now()

let x = default(d)
```

However, this **can not** work, as `now()` can not work at compiletime. Similarly, `dateTime` and `initDateTime` break at compiletime.

It is unlikely that the actual value will ever be used, I just need a way to instantiate objects so that other packages can replace the values later on (e.g. `norm` when parsing data from a database into that object).
Given that, how can I instantiate a DateTime to make objects with such fields default initializable?

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are trying to do is… weird? You mention you want to instantiate objects so that others replace the values… but that does not seem to fit the idea of a constant compile time value which can't be modified. Anyway, if you look at [the source of the default proc](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/version-1-6/lib/system.nim#L982) you can copy its signature and replace it with something more specific for your use case. Example:

```
import std/times

type A = object
  d: DateTime

let x = default(A)
echo x

proc default(T: typedesc[A]): A =
  result.d = times.now()

let y = default(A)
echo y
```

Running this example with Nim 1.4.8 would echo:

```
(d: Uninitialized DateTime)
(d: 2022-10-24T23:30:28+02:00)
```

So in theory you could define `default` procs for all your custom types and expose them along those types. Source code importing those types would also get the type specific `default` procs, which would be used in preference to the system one.

*Update*: As for the actual question itself (How to instantiate a `DateTime` object at compile time?), if you modify that example [to use constant expressions](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#constants-and-constant-expressions):

```
import std/times

type A = object
  d: DateTime

proc default(T: typedesc[A]): A =
  result.d = times.now()

const y = default(A)
static:
  echo y
```

You get the expected compile time error:

> ~/.choosenim/toolchains/nim-1.4.8/lib/pure/times.nim(899, 5) Error: cannot 'importc' variable at compile time; gettimeofday

It's *funny* that a *pure* module actually depends on `importc` (shouldn't that mean it's not that pure really?) but the problem could be avoided if you wrote your own `times.now()` implementation. Maybe there's a Nim macro to return the current time of the way in a compiler friendly way, and if all else fails maybe you could pass the compilation time as a `define` to the compiler and slap it into the `DateTime` structure directly. Remember it's a normal structure you can look into and modify as you want, you can always provide alternative ways to initialise it which don't depend on procs only available at runtime.

Comment: For context:I mostly want to use the new default feature on nim's devel branch for what I currently use the constructor package: Have a low-code way to get a construction proc where fields have valid values. I want this because norm, an ORM in nim, takes instantiated objects as blue prints, copies them and replaces their values with data queried and parsed from the database. So I need to pass norm *some* sort of instance from my type where all fields have valid values.

Comment: As for the suggestion to write the overload the default proc - That is possible, but goes against the purpose of wanting to use the new "default instance" feature of nim in the first place - If I wanted to write my own procs, I'd just write them as `init(typedesc)` or `new(typedesc)`, but that's a ton of typing for many types. The entire idea is to just do `=` assignments of default values on the type and nim provides a proc for you ( `default`) that generates instances with these values for you. see https://github.com/beef331/constructor for comparison, it is that but as a language feature.